# Swift Get all the properties in generic class

Tags: swift, mirror

I'm trying to get all the members of a generic class `T`, I can get the `properties` based on a specific `class`. 
But, how I can do it using `Mirror` ?

```
let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: user)

for (index, attr) in mirrored_object.children.enumerated() {
  if let propertyName = attr.label as String! {
    print("Attr \(index): \(propertyName) = \(attr.value)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Swift does not have reflection. You can poke around a bit with `Mirror`, but it is very likely not going to be what you're looking for. There is no general way to do what you're describing in Swift today.

Comment: There are third party reflection libraries that work off current (unstable) Swift ABI. They'll work, but expect major downtime when Swift update introduce breaking ABI changes. https://github.com/Zewo/Reflection

Comment: @Alexander, yes, it works, but that already exists in swift 3 and 4 as you can see in the example, but for generic T types?

Comment: @MrMins "but that already exists in swift 3 and 4 as you can see in the example" Uhhhh no, no it doesn't. Spend a minute on that page, then compare to what `Mirror` can('t) do.

Comment: Do you guys think someday Apple will release kind of reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this as extension

```
extension NSObject {
    public func GetAsJson() -> [[String:Any?]] {
        var result:[[String: Any?]] = [[String: Any?]]()

        for item in self {
            var dict: [String: Any?] = [:]
            for property in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
                dict[property.label!] = property.value
            }
            result.append(dict)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```